# How can I delete my repository in GitHub?

Tags: github

I have a Git repository hosted on GitHub that I would like to delete. I have tried looking for a delete button, but cannot find it.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on your repository.

Go to the Settings tab.

Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page.

You will be asked for a confirmation, and you will have to enter your password again.

[image]